# xxhdpi density added in API 16, what in <16 if I provide only xxhdpi resources?

Tags: android, bitmap, android-drawable, android-resources, android-screen-support

I'm working on a porting from iOS to Android, and since the iOS guy gave me only *@3x* versions of all graphic resources, I have placed them only in the *res/drawable-xxhdpi* folder. I know it's not a good practice to not provide alternative low-res resources, but according to official documentation:

> By default, Android scales your bitmap drawables [...] so that they render at the appropriate physical size on each device. For example, if your application provides bitmap drawables only for [...] medium screen density (mdpi), then the system scales them up when on a high-density screen, and scales them down when on a low-density screen.

Now, documentation also says:

> *xxhdpi:* Extra-extra-high-density screens; approximately 480dpi. **Added in API Level 16**

Then, my question. I don't give any bitmap alternatives aside from *xxhdpi*, so on devices running Android API <16 will this drawables be rendered at all? I tried the app on an API 10 emulator, and all my stuff is there. Should it be? If yes, **why**?!?

Comment: well yes the size will change but did you think about resolution?

Comment: @AndroidProgrammer sorry but I can't understand your question

Answer (score 3):

The answer is yes, your resources will be rendered even on devices with API < 16.

Why yes?

This is just a finding: If you look inside the contents of the output apk res folder. The drawble-xxhdpi resource folder is converted to drawble-xxhdpi-v4

[image]

v4 qualifier gets appended with the drawable-xxhdpi folder. The v4 support library was designed to be used with Android 1.6 (API level 4) and this might have a connection that new qualifier resources are detected even on lower API devices.

Qualifiers have been defined to support different resolution devices in a better way. Once you're able to compile your APK with API >= 16 and a lower API device is supported by your app, the resources from new qualifier folders will be picked even on lower API devices if none of the compatible qualifier resources are detected.

Your test on API 10 emulator confirms this.

You should check the best practices, but I understand the question was not about that.

Comment: I tried to remove v4 support library from the project, and xxhpi resources are still visible. I also tried to set `targetSdkVersion` to 10, but they are still there...

Comment: Yes they would remain visible

Comment: @lorenzo-s, I think the "v4" should mean the qualifier for api levels, which has nothing to do with "v4 support library".See "http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources"

Answer (score 0):

I would really stay away from loading 3x images for lower-resolution devices. Those phones already have limited memory and loading such large images will use up a lot of memory. You should use tools to resize the images for you in all the different densities. Try using this https://github.com/redwarp/9-Patch-Resizer

If you really want to keep one version of the image, put it in the drawable folder (not drawable-xxhdpi). (not recommended because you'll end up with poor looking images on some devices)

Comment: Agree with this except the last part -- you really shouldn't put bitmap images in the root drawable directory; they'll get upscaled as though they're mdpi assets, and it'll look awful on high density screens.

Comment: It is drawable and not drawables folder

Comment: Ok, I can agree with you, as I said, I know it's not a good practice. But my question is completely different.